# How to enforce Selinux (setprop ro.boot.selinux=enforcing)

Tags: xiaomi, selinux

I have a Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro (raphael, China Version) device.
I set the prop "ro.boot.selinux" to "permissive", by installing [this Magisk Module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magisk-selinux-manager-t3760042).
Now I'd like to set it back to "enforcing", but didn't find a way to do so.

I tried using the Module to reset the prop and got this Error: "This root method has no boot script support!
!You will need to add init.d support!
!Addon.d not detected. Backup script not installed..." 
It further says it installs files and reports a success, but selinux is still permissive.

After a couple hours on google now, I still don't know what init.d support really is and how I set it up. I hope you can help me.

I tried further:

setenforce 1 -> works till reboot

edit sys/fs/selinux/enforce to 1 -> back to 0 after reboot

setprop ro.boot.selinux=enforcing from terminal in twrp -> error: "unable to set property "ro.boot.selinux" to "enforcing" error code 0xb"

flash both, a recovery.img and boot.img with "androidboot.selinux=enforcing" via fastboot

flash stock miui 11

flash stock miui 10 and upgrade to miui 11

getenforce still results in permissive :/

Thanks a lot!

Edit: After reflashing LOS17 and Magisk and using the module again, I managed to set selinux back to enforcing. Now the popup camera comes up on every boot though, lol
This can be closed, thx

Comment: consider answering your own question with reproduceable steps

Comment: The only step is to delete the module or `init.d` script which executes `setenforce 0` on boot. `ro.boot.selinux` was abandoned back in Android 6, replacing with kernel cmdline parameter.